# Why does e in edition and eleven have difference sounds?

Tags: pronunciation

> edition  ɪˈdɪʃn̩
>
> eleven  ɪˈlevn̩

[Edition](https://forvo.com/word/edition/#en), I hear this e sounds like a as in (a pen).

[Eleven](https://forvo.com/word/eleven/#en), e sounds like short e.

Comment: I think you'll find this varies widely among English dialects and from speaker to speaker. Some speakers would use the same "e" sound for both words.

Comment: There are differences that matter (they change one word into a different word) and difference that don't (they are 'the same sound'). The 'e' of 'edition' and the 'e' of 'eleven' are 'the same sound'.
Another issue is that one is followed by 'd' and the other by 'l'. 'l' often changes the vowel before it.

Comment: *Eleven* has three *e*s. Which one are you asking about? The first one? Note that the first *e* in *eleven* can also be pronounced as if it were a long *e* (as in *eel*). There is no single way of saying it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That is one of the best known characteristics of the English language. A blessing and a curse. That is why you must always have the pronunciation of the word available when you learn English.

For more "amusement", read [**this discussion**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31991/why-does-the-ending-ough-have-six-pronunciations) about the reading of: cough, tough, bough, through, and though.

Another "amusement": the letter "c" is read differently each time it appears in "The Pa***c***ifi***c*** O***c***ean".

Comment: There's now another word in the list of the *ough* words--[***hough***](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/270688/106592). And this time the *-gh* is pronounced /k/ i.e. /hɒk/.